# AugularJS with nested JSON and views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I'm new with ionic so start playing with a starter. I'm building a book library like app for inhouse purpose and here's my **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TjDOfYgcrlpZuOmGkiLw?p=preview)**.

I have my book data in a json stored in **services.js**
As you can see it's a nested json with several book categories, each category will have a number of books.
I have managed to extract category information from it and pull them into a list using ng-repeat.

What I want to achieve is when you click one of the categories, it will go to a view/page, listing all the books of that category (**template file chat-detail.html**). 
Then if you click on a certain book it will open detail page (template not made as I could not pass last step).

I'm trying to get category name with below code:

```
get: function(catname) {
  for (var i = 0; i < chats[0].categories.length; i++) {
    if (chats[0].categories[i].catname === catname) {
      return chats[0].categories[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

I did a console.log and I can see that array returned as expected.

But when I click on the category list nothing happens, the error message is not user friendly at all. Something start with Injector unpr then follows with hundreds of lines. AngularJS docs say this is related to unmatch controller name but I've triple checked my names and they look good to me.

I'm stuck here for the whole week, anyone would shed any light on this would be much appreciated.

You can directly modify with **[my code here](http://plnkr.co/edit/TjDOfYgcrlpZuOmGkiLw?p=preview)**  I have a feeling that I'm having problem with my controllers.js, just don't know where.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced your `ionic.bundle.min.js` with a [non-minified version](http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-rc.2/js/ionic.bundle.js) and the got the following error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: appTabsProvider <- appTabs
>   <- AppTabs

This states that angular is unable to resolve the `appTabs` dependency.

In your `controller.js` I replaced this:

```
.controller('AppTabs', function($scope, $stateParams, appTabs) {
    appTabs.displayEffect();
})
```

with this to resolve the dependency error.

```
.controller('AppTabs', function($scope, $stateParams, ionicMaterialInk) {
    ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();
})
```

I don't know if this was what you were going for, but i saw `ionicMaterialInk.displayEffect();` being used elsewhere.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thank you but this does not solve the problem. I got a blank page instead, also messed up with the view, unable to navigate to other tabs after replacing with your code.